# How to link post image to post link?

Tags: theme-development, themes

For my client site, I am planning to enable link post image to post a link on blog list page, the site uses custom WordPress theme developed by the previous developer.

For blog post list page he created as content.php and for the single post he created `content-page.php`

Even if I add the featured image I can't able to see that featured image, only the image inside of the post is showing.

How to achieve this?

Here is the code for content.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Blog
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        if ( is_single() ) :
            the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
        else :
            the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"  rel="bookmark" >', '</a></h2>' );
        endif;

        if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :  ?>
        <h4 class="meta text-muted">
            <?php bfablog_posted_on(); ?>
        </h4><!-- .entry-meta -->
        <?php
        endif; ?>
        <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox_mzc3" style="margin-bottom:20px;" data-title="<?php the_title() ?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" </div>
        <!-- AddThis Button END -->

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">


        <?php
                     the_content( sprintf (
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post. */
                wp_kses(__( 'Read more', 'bfablog' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => 
array() ) ) ),

                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
            ) );


               wp_link_pages( array(
                            'before' => '<div class= "page-links">'. esc_html__('Pages:', 'bfablog'
),

                           'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <?php bfablog_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
<hr>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var addthis_config = {
    ui_language: "{{ site.lang }}"
  };
  var addthis_share =
  {
     // ... members go here
  }
</script>

<!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-586c401922d76d24"></script>
```

Here is the code for content-page.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying page content in page.php
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package BfA_Blog
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content"><hr>
        <?php
            the_content();


            wp_link_pages(array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__('Pages:','bfablog'),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->


    <?php if ( get_edit_post_link() ) : ?>
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php
                edit_post_link(
                    sprintf(
                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                        esc_html__( 'Edit %s', 'bfablog' ),
                        the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
                    ),
                    '<span class="edit-link">',
                    '</span>'
                );
            ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding `bitly` links, I removed it from the post as the question can be explained even without it. If you think it's required please add the site URL not the bitly one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, you want to show the featured image and link it to the single post page? The content.php is the loop being used to display the content. So this is the place where you want to place the featured image.

To show the featured image in the archive or posts list, edit content.php. In the header tag of the article, Do this.

```
   if ( is_single() ) :
        the_post_thumbnail('large'); // If you want to show the featured image in the single post page
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    else :
        the_post_thumbnail('large'); // If you want to show the image in the archive. You can change the location if before or after title
        the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"  rel="bookmark" >', '</a></h2>' );
    endif;
```

Steps to edit the content.php

First, this answer is based on the notion that your client is using a featured image. If not, then I can no longer understand what you guys are trying to achieve :(

1. Login to Wordpress
2. Appearance -> Editor
3. Find and click content.php in the right side of the page
4. Backup the current codes in there and paste the code in the pastebin below.

https://pastebin.com/cEAFHntg

Hope this works for you, if not it is best to find a developer.

Comment: thanks for reply , now i want to link the post in the post images that shows in the archive or posts list,  how edit the (content.php is the loop being used to display the content) ??

Comment: thanks for reply ,I am new to wordpress development, now clients dont wants to use featured image , they just asking with the current blog post list view page , if i click the image that should open the post page,i dont know  how to edit the (content.php is the loop being used to display the content) ??

Comment: i have enabled the code you provided but its not working properly, can you see the site again? and find the problem

Comment: You did not provide a link.

Comment: i have enabled your code but some links showing in the posts and featured image not showing on single post page site url: http://blog.biblesforamerica.org/

Comment: It's because the blog posts do not have featured image. So there's nothing to show. This will work if you are not inserting the image inside the content and you use featured images. Please revert back the code to the previous one. Sorry.

Comment: hi, i have enbaled the featured post for this post: http://blog.biblesforamerica.org/the-key-to-true-inner-peace/ now please check, and i want to display the image below the title and meta information and social sharing

Comment: Check out this updated bin https://pastebin.com/svpAeQzS

Comment: how about showing the featured image on archive page ?

Comment: Simply remove the if condition https://pastebin.com/CbHnBBsV

Comment: thank you so much bro, but i another doubts , now i removed the post image and uploaded the featured image , in the archive page featured image links works fine, but i dont want to enable the link on single post image , how to disable the link on single post ?

Comment: Remove the links if single https://pastebin.com/PfAXjUfz

Comment: Thank you so much bro :) , now its working fine, but sorry to distrub u , i want to ask another doubts ,

If i enable the featured image on archive page and enabled the post image in the single post like in the single post page the post image will show, but if i enable the featured image on archive page both post image and featured image will show in the archive page right?  How to disable the post image on archive page bro?

Comment: Sure. https://pastebin.com/eL70g4JW

Comment: Thank you bro! i have another doubts on creating the page , shall i ask here or on separate questions?

Comment: Do it in a separate question. This thread is already too long

Comment: ok bro,this is the question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/280401/design-view-breaking-on-pages

Answer (score 0):

Your previous developer haven't called featured image in listing page and not even in single page. Here is the code to add featured image and linked to single post page.

```
<div class="featured-image">
  <a href="<?phpthe_permalink(); ?>">
  <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( $size ); ?>" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

You can place this code above or below the title where ever you want and you can style the way you want.
Cheers!

Comment: thanks for reply umer shoukat , now i want to link the post in the post images that shows in the archive or posts list,  how edit the (content.php is the loop being used to display the content) ??

Comment: You can place same code with in the loop of your archive template or where ever you are listing your posts. Don't forget to mark answer as correct. :)

Comment: I am new to wordpress development, now clients dont wants to use featured image , they just asking with the current blog post list view page , if i click the image that should open the post page, i dont know how to

Comment: The solution is already there. I am so sorry but i can't help more than this. You're not capable of understand things. You better find a developer for this. it's a 5min task for correct person. 
Thanks

Comment: if i am not capable of understand things , as the senior developer you need to help Bro umer ? you should not blame not tease

Comment: I am not teasing you. Giving you the best and time saving solution. I told you the solution is already there in my answer which you are looking for. If i had another way to help i would definitely do that. Search my name on google and contact me on my facebook or upwork profile. Thanks